# Proof that $Qo(n) = 2(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i)+2n = n^2 + n$

Tags: proof-verification, summation

So i would appreciate if someone explain to me the step by step on how do i get this result

$Qo(n) = 2(\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i)+2n = n^2 + n$

How do you proof that it is $=n^2+n$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, it is a standard result that $\sum_{i=1}^n i = \frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$. If not, then summing the two series in reverse and dividing by 2 gets you the expression.

Anywho, we now have: $Q_0(n) = 2 \cdot \frac{1}{2}n(n-1) + 2n = n^2 -n + 2n = n^2 + n$ as required.

Answer (score 2):

The sequence,

$$1,2,3,4,5,6,...,n-1$$

Is uniformly varied, thus its average is the average of its first and last term:

$$\frac{1+(n-1)}{2}=\frac{n}{2}$$

If we want to sum all the terms in the sequence we can use the fact that the average A follows:

$$A=\frac{n}{2}=\frac{\mathbb{SUM}}{n-1}$$

Because there are $n-1$ terms in the sequence,

Thus,

$$\mathbb{SUM}=(n-1)\frac{n}{2}=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} i$$

And you can go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I could not understand your problem very well, but if your problem is the second equality, it is concluded from $\sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$.

Comment: Your equation is incorrect.

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n i \neq \frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.